# Generic DotLess .box-shadow mixin with support RTL?

Tags: css, less, dotless

First of all am not perfect in writing less mixins.
I need to write a mixin to support RTL & LTR for box-shadow CSS property. I have a global variable for direction called @direction. what I did is defining two mixins for both LTR & RTL depending on the @direction variable

```
.shadow(LTR, @inset: "inset", @hOffset, @vOffset, @blur, @color) {
    @localizedShadow: @inset @hOffset @vOffset @blur @color;
}
.shadow(RTL, @inset: "inset", @hOffset, @vOffset, @blur, @color) {
    @localizedShadow: @inset (@hOffset * -1) @vOffset @blur @color;
}
```

after that I add 2 more mixins for the box-shadow property

```
.box-shadow(LTR, @inset: "inset", @hOffset, @vOffset, @blur, @color) {
    .shadow(LTR, @inset: "inset", @hOffset, @vOffset, @blur, @color);
    .box-shadow(@localizedShadow);
}
.box-shadow(RTL, @inset: "inset", @hOffset, @vOffset, @blur, @color) {
    .shadow(RTL, @inset: "inset", @hOffset, @vOffset, @blur, @color);
    .box-shadow(@localizedShadow);
}
```

based on that I'm unable to compile because of parsing error.

what I'm trying to achieve is to use my mixin like that

```
.box-shadow(@direction; @hOffset: 1px; @vOffset: 1px; @blur: 1px;, @color: rgba(0,0,0,.075))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: Parse Error! that's it

Comment: No mention of file/line where this happens? Okay. Now how the actuall mixin that outputs the `box-shadow` properties is defined? (the one you call with `.box-shadow(@localizedShadow);`).

Comment: Also, `;,` in your last statement, is it just a typo in the Q only or it appears same way in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay then, if you just want to an "overloaded" box-shadow you can simplify it to just:

```
.box-shadow(LTR, @inset: inset, @hOffset, @vOffset, @blur, @color) {
    box-shadow: @inset @hOffset @vOffset @blur @color;
}
.box-shadow(RTL, @inset: inset, @hOffset, @vOffset, @blur, @color) {
    box-shadow: @inset (@hOffset * -1) @vOffset @blur @color;
}
```

Usage:

```
.test {
    .box-shadow(LTR, inset, 1px, 1px, 1px, red);
}
```

Comment: `@{localizedShadow}: @inset @hOffset @vOffset @blur @color;`this line I'm trying to initialize new variable which called localizedShadow so that I can reuse it or use the mixin return value in the .box-shadow mixin

Comment: Th above solution by @Neps should also work with the `.box-shadow()` mixin. You could replace `box-shadow: @inset @hOffset @vOffset @blur @color;`  with `.box-shadow(@inset @hOffset @vOffset @blur @color);` and  `box-shadow: @inset (@hOffset * -1) @vOffset @blur @color;` with `.box-shadow(@inset (@hOffset * -1) @vOffset @blur @color;)`, see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvMxaE. All .box-shadow mixins only match on argument matching. Notice that when you only use the .box-shadow  mixin to set the vendor prefixes you should prefer to use (the) autoprefixer post processor.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it works here

```
.shadow(LTR; @i: inset; @x; @y; @b; @c) {
    @shadow: ~"@{i} @{x} @{y} @{b} @{c}";
}

.shadow(RTL; @i: inset; @x; @y; @b; @c) {
    @xNew: @x * -1;
    @shadow: ~"@{i} @{xNew} @{y} @{b} @{c}";
}

.box-shadow(LTR; @i: inset; @x; @y; @b; @c) {
    .shadow(LTR; @i; @x; @y; @b; @c);
    .box-shadow(@shadow);
}
.box-shadow(RTL; @i: inset; @x; @y; @b; @c) {
    .shadow(RTL; @i; @x; @y; @b; @c);
    .box-shadow(@shadow);
}

.box-shadow(@shadow) {
    -webkit-box-shadow: @shadow;
    box-shadow: @shadow;
}
```